# Cakephp: question about saveall() with multiselect

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm wondering what the cleanest way is to implement a cakephp form where 1 control is a multi-select and the rest are text fields or single-selects, and then the data is inserted as multiple rows with a saveall(). So for example a form is selected with these values:

textfield A
value=Foo

mulit-select B
values=US,Mexico,Canada

single=select C
value=10

and so I want to insert these rows into the database with a saveall():
Foo,US,10
Foo,Mexico,10
Foo,Canada,10

Now I know in the add view I can use this format for the input statement:

input('Model.0.field1',...)

but I'm wondering if I can mix that in that same form with inputs formatted like 
input('Model.field2',....).

Update:
When I mix and match the single-select and multiple-select controls, the form data gets submitted like this:

```
Array
(
    [Alert] => Array
        (
            [schedule_id] => 75
            [user_id] => 6
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [frequency] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => WEEKLY
                            [1] => MONTHLY
                        )

                )

            [limit_value] => .03
            [limit_adjustment] => 0
            [type] => LIMIT
            [disabled] => 0
        )

)
```

I tried passing that data into saveall() but it treats it like a single record.

Update2: I think saveAll() requires that the multiple rows of data be formatted like this:

```
Array
(
    [Article] => Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                            [title] => title 1
                        )
            [1] => Array
                (
                            [title] => title 2
                        )
                )
)
```

So it looks like after the submit I'm going to need some javascript code that will restructure the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something that works... I'm not sure if it takes full advantage of all of cake's "automagic" capabilities, but I don't think it's too convoluted.

So I just added the following code to my controller's add function:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
            //debug($this->data, true);

                       /* begin custom code */
            $multiselect = $this->data['Alert']['entity_id'];

            $tmp2 = array();
            foreach ($multiselect as $item)
            {
                $tmp = $this->data['Alert'];
                $tmp['entity_id'] = $item;
                array_push($tmp2,$tmp);

            }

            $this->data['Alert'] = $tmp2;

            debug($this->data,true);
            /* end custom code */

            $this->Alert->create();

            //restructure data





            if ($this->Alert->saveAll($this->data['Alert'])) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The alert has been saved', true));
                //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The alert could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
```

and that converts my data to this:

```
Array
(
    [Alert] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [schedule_id] => 74
                    [entity_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 6
                    [frequency] => HOURLY
                    [limit_value] => .02
                    [limit_adjustment] => 0
                    [type] => LIMIT
                    [disabled] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [schedule_id] => 74
                    [entity_id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 6
                    [frequency] => HOURLY
                    [limit_value] => .02
                    [limit_adjustment] => 0
                    [type] => LIMIT
                    [disabled] => 1
                )

        )

)
```